# Low search showing repeating/too many results

Tags: templates, search, low-search

The search is returning too many results and repeating the same result entries more then once.

I have a second collection set up almost exactly the same which doesn't do this.

Any idea what is going on?
Thanks for looking.

Search box code

```
  {exp:low_search:form result_page="publications/pub_results"}
     <fieldset>
       <input type="search" name="keywords" id="keywords"/>
       <button type="submit">Search Publications</button>
     </fieldset>
  {/exp:low_search:form}
```

Results page code (with mark up simplified)

```
    {exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" limit="10" collection="publications_c" search_mode="auto"}
  {if count ==  1}

           <p>{pub_year}</p>

              <h4 style="margin-left:12px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px;"><a href="{url_title}">{full_title}.</a></h4> 


                   {/if}

             {if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
                {if no_results}<p>No search results. Check your spelling or try a different search term.</p>{/if}
              {/exp:low_search:results}
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params):

> [P]arameters can be applied in two ways: as input fields in a Form, or as hard-coded parameters in the Results or URL tag.

That means the Form tag doesn't accept any filter parameters, like `collection` and `search_mode`, which are part of the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords). So try moving those parameters to the Results tag instead.

Also, the parameter `name` is not a valid on the Form tag. If you're trying to set an html attribute to the form-tag, use `form_name` instead.

**Edit:** After [investigation](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/returning-too-many-results-repeating-the-same-result-or-none-at-all), it turned out the Results tag was nested inside a channel:entries tag, and the code inside the Results tag was wrapped inside a `{if count == 1}` conditional. The problem was solved after these issues were addressed.

Comment: I updated the <form? tags etc. I still getting same sort of results. What might you suggest? Do you know is there a current beginners tutorial with examples out there perhaps. Feeling a bit lost. Thanks!!

Comment: updated the  question above

Comment: If the updated code is giving you unexpected results, please submit a support request over at [the official Low support forums](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/), along with version info and template debugger output.